# Do magic statics guarantee that right side is executed only once?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-initialization

If I have

```
atomic<int> cnt=0;

int get_int() noexcept
{
   cnt++;
   return rand();
}
```

and then:

```
void func()
{
   static const auto value = get_int();
}
```

I know that there will be no race condition on initialization of `value`, but I don't know if 
`get_int()` will be called once, or in my example will `cnt` be 1 (and not 2, 3, 4, or 5).

Assume multiple threads enter `func()` and `get_int` has only 1 callsite in `func()`.

Comment: If worried about multiple threads calling `func` at once, I think you could use something like `std::call_once([] {cnt++;});`

Comment: cnt is just an example, I am actually worried about leaking since my real get_int function actually returns pointer to object that it allocates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++11 guarantees that there will be no race condition *N3797 - §6.7/4*:

> An implementation is permitted to perform early initialization of other block-scope variables with static or
>       thread storage duration under the same conditions that an implementation is permitted to statically initialize
>       a variable with static or thread storage duration in namespace scope (3.6.2). Otherwise such a variable is
>       initialized the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon
>       the completion of its initialization. If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization
>       is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration. If control enters
>       the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for
>       completion of the initialization.92 If control re-enters the declaration recursively while the variable is being
>       initialized, the behavior is undefined. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> int foo(int i) {
>   static int s = foo(2*i); // recursive call - undefined
>   return i+1;
> }
> ```
>
> *- end example* ]

It's not re-entrant but thread-safe. Make sure there will not be other parts of the code that will call `get_int()` before `func()` anyway.

Comment: Paragraph 4 in §6.7 is cited as "6.7/4", or better yet using the section tags "[stmt.dcl]/4". The section numbers change as the standard evolves, but the tags stay the same.

Comment: @Casey Thanks, also for the formatting. I was wrestling the quote tag before

Answer (score 2):

`get_int()` will be called only once from that line , but given your code, `get_int()` could be called beforehand from different locations in the code.